# Сохранение и загрузка файлов в Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Как можно сохранить массив строк в файл, а также этот файл обратно загрузить в программу.

Comment: а для чего вам это?

Comment: Для приложения, в котором можно создать тест, сохранить его и скинуть кому-нибудь, после чего человека на этом же приложении может его пройти

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов

1. [SQLite](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) - создание базы данных.
2. Запись в Local storage или External Storage. Сериализация происходит в общем проекте. Но надо сначала запросить разрешения, типа `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. [Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/)
3. Или [словарь Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary:%7E:text=page%20here%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20Properties,%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%20Application%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82,-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20Properties), который позволяет хранить данные

Answer (score 0):

1. "File System Plugin for Xamarin and Windows" или множество других плагинов вам в помошь. Он создаст файл, сохранит данные, прочитает.

public async Task CreateRealFileAsync()
        {
            // get hold of the file system
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

```
        // create a folder, if one does not exist already
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        // create a file, overwriting any existing file
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // populate the file with some text
        await file.WriteAllTextAsync("Sample Text...");
```

}

2. а потом в платформе реализует Share Service. 
   Android:

   public class Share: IShare
   {
       private readonly Context _context;
       public Share()
       {
           _context = Android.App.Application.Context;
       }

   ```
   public Task Show(string title, string message, string filePath)
   {
       var extension = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
       var contentType = string.Empty;

       // You can manually map more ContentTypes here if you want.
       switch (extension)
       {
           case "pdf":
               contentType = "application/pdf";
               break;
           case "png":
               contentType = "image/png";
               break;
           default:
               contentType = "application/octetstream";
               break;
       }

       var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
       intent.SetType(contentType);
       intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Uri.Parse("file://" + filePath));
       intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, string.Empty);
       intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, message ?? string.Empty);

       var chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, title ?? string.Empty);
       chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
       chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
       _context.StartActivity(chooserIntent);

       return Task.FromResult(true);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Реализуйте ассоциацию приложения с вашим типом файлов, чтобы открыть на втором телефоне(к примеру при получении по email).
   Ну или свой велосипед по передачи между телефонами.

Comment: У вас есть пример приложения в Xamarin.Android? Не особо понял выше написанный код.

Comment: только клиентский(поэтому могу только принцип рассказать), а сами примеры в принципе на официальном сайте/поисковике доступны. Осталось собрать воедино. 1- Сохраните. 2-Отправьте (https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/email/send_an_email/ вот вам еще. но только без вложения файла). Установите ассоциацию в настройках проекта, для открытия файлов вашего передаваемого типа